# How to access an object from a form to another class in c#.net

Tags: c#

I have a form named `frmMain.cs` that contains two(2) text boxes, `txtUsername`, and `txtPassword`, I want to access them in the class that I created named `CheckIfUsernameAndPasswordExist.cs` please note that the two objects modifier is in public already. when I use the correct class name of `frmMain.cs` the error says that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property" so I create a new instance of that `class "frmMain formMain = new frmMain();"` but the problem when I run my program those objects are empty so that it cannot access my database values. please help me, thank you. I'm a newbie in C#.

```
frmMain formMain = new frmMain();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", formMain.txtUsername.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", formMain.txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: The easiest way is to simply pass them in. What piece of code creates the instance of `CheckIfUsernameAndPasswordExist` and calls it? Do you call it from within `frmMain`, or from somewhere else?

Comment: "[Tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)". You need a userPassValidationService, that does what you want. Pass (inject) that service into frmMain. Then call it there. (That's Inversion Of Control) SideNote: I really really hope, you are _not_ saving passwords in clear-text, do you?

Comment: @MarkNartea You didn't answer my question. Please reread carefully.

Comment: "I want to call those two" - you do not "call" properties.

Comment: BTW: _"the two objects modifier is in public"_ A public property "txtPassword" should trigger some alarm bells. You'd want to have a plain text password field as private as can be.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most practical way is to simply pass the values of `txtUsername.Text` and `txtPassword.Text` to your `Authentication.cs` class (or in your case is called `CheckIfUsernameAndPasswordExist.cs`) after the user presses the `Submit` button.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool blnRes = Authentication.Authenicate(txtUsername.Text.Trim(),
                                             txtPassword.Text.Trim());
}
```

Comment: You can even pass the control, in case you are constantly monitoring their content:

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        bool blnRes = Authentication.Authenicate(txtUsername, txtPassword);
    }

... where txtUsername and txtPassword are of type TextBox.

Comment: @MiguelMateo that would introduce a dependency to the UI Controls in the ValidationClass. Not something I would do nor want, but well ...

Comment: @Fildor yet it is useful when you have multi tasks app, running concurrent thread in the end, checking for the status of those text boxes and/or updating your GUI (changing labels for example).

Comment: @MiguelMateo Why would you do that? You can perfectly use the controls' events to trigger validation on demand. No threads needed.

Comment: @Fildor, please note the original question.  One of the possible answers is sending the values.  I extended that you can even send the controls if required.  In my case, it has been useful to update labels in the GUI with results calculated in backend threads, as the thread continues running.

Comment: @MiguelMateo Yes, I don't argue that. I just don't see how that's applicable here. But fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Create new frmMain will give you completely new object with all its variable as a default initialized what you need to do is to create new static class that store username and password and use them in your code